# Match a word but not a larger word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want a regex to match `rov` but there's a thousand occurences of `prov` that I'm not interested in, so I need to match `rov` but exclude `prov`.

I've tried `/((?!prov).)*(rov)/i` but that still matches the `rov` part in the word `prov`. I also tried `/((?!prov).)*(^rov)/i` but I can't use it, I need to match words like `CreateRov`, I can't use `^` or `\b`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps like `\b(?!p)\w*rov\w*\b` https://regex101.com/r/D8czUO/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird It looks like it works but it matches `prov` when it's not the at the begging of the line (it doesn't match `prov` but it matches `getProv` or `aaaprov` so it's not very useful)

Comment: I have added an updated version as an answer which will match those values.

Comment: Why should `CreateRov` match while `prov` shouldn't? Is it because of that case change?

Comment: Try `(?<!p)rov\b` or `(?<!p)rov` alone.

Comment: @sp00m Any word containing `rov` should match, unless it contains `prov`. `aaarovaaa`should match but `arovaaprova` should not.

Comment: Ok thanks, and which programming language are you using? Do you know if the regex flavour it uses supports negative lookbehinds?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing two regexes might be the easier option here. First extract all matches for `rov` then filter out the matches for `prov`.

Comment: @sp00m I'm using Eclipse, doing a File Search with "Regular expression". Not sure what flavor it's using. Btw I don't know how to make flags work, I need it to be case insensitive but /regex/i doesn't match anything

Comment: There should be a checkbox for case-sensitiveness.

Comment: OK, [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358118/1225328)'s is the one I ended up with too. I guess Eclipse supports negative lookbehind so you can also give a try too `(?<!p)rov`. I don't use Eclipse, but on IntelliJ, don't use any regex delimiter (i.e. directly `regex` instead of `/regex/`), and flags are handled via checkboxes (e.g. look for "case insensitive search" or the like if you want `i`).

Comment: Another idea without lookaround: `(?i)\b(?:\w*?[^\Wp])?rov\w*\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not prov right after matching a word boundary.

Then match `rov` between matching 0+ word characters on the left and right.

```
\b(?!\w*prov)\w*rov\w*\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!\w*prov)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `prov`
- `\w*rov\w*` Match `rov` between matching 0+ word chars on the left an right
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBT9Ro/1)

Comment: it matches `aprov` and it's not what I want. Any string with `p` immediately before `rov` must not be matched.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Like this? https://regex101.com/r/2zyDTp/1

Comment: Not sure, but if you want to make the pattern case insensitive, you might try an line flag `(?i)\b(?!\w*prov)\w*rov\w*\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird good call, forgot about this notation.